# AppDispatcher.register() fires once, but not a second time?

Tags: reactjs, flux, reactjs-flux

We're building a react/flux app and have run into a strange problem where we dispatch an action **ACCOUNT_ACTION_TYPES.LOAD_ACCOUNT** and it's handled by AppDispatcher.register() without issue, but when the second dispatched action **ACCOUNT_ACTION_TYPES.LOAD_ACCOUNT_SUCCESS** is sent AppDispatcher.register() never handles it.

```
AppDispatcher.register(function (action)
{
    /// <summary>This is the Dispatcher Register Function</summary>
    /// <param name="action" type="Action" optional="false">The Action object to process</param>

    switch (action.type) {
        case ACCOUNT_ACTION_TYPES.LOAD_ACCOUNT:
            {
                console.log(ACCOUNT_ACTION_TYPES.LOAD_ACCOUNT);
                AccountStore.loading(true);
                //AccountStore[.error(null);

                AccountStore.triggerChange();
                break;
            }

        case ACCOUNT_ACTION_TYPES.LOAD_ACCOUNT_SUCCESS:
            {
                console.log(ACCOUNT_ACTION_TYPES.LOAD_ACCOUNT_SUCCESS);
                AccountStore.loading(false);
                //AccountStore.error(null);
                AccountStore.setAccount(action.data);

                AccountStore.triggerChange();
                break;
            }
    }

    return true; // Needed for Flux promise resolution
});
```

Here's the dispatching code:

```
var AccountActions = {
    loadAccount: function (accountId)
    {
        AppDispatcher.dispatch(new Action(ACCOUNT_ACTION_TYPES.LOAD_ACCOUNT));

        webAppsAPI.accounts.get(accountId, function (response)
        {
            AppDispatcher.dispatch(new Action(ACCOUNT_ACTION_TYPES.LOAD_ACCOUNT_SUCCESS, response));
        });
    }
};
```

When we dig into AppDispatcher.dispatch() on the first action **this._callbacks** has an ID_1 property. On the second dispatch **this._callbacks** is empty, so the action is never actually dispatched, but WHY?! What gives :s

```
Dispatcher.prototype.dispatch = function dispatch(payload)
            {
                !!this._isDispatching ? true ? invariant(false, 'Dispatch.dispatch(...): Cannot dispatch in the middle of a dispatch.') : invariant(false) : undefined;
                this._startDispatching(payload);
                try {
                    for (var id in this._callbacks) {
                        if (this._isPending[id]) {
                            continue;
                        }
                        this._invokeCallback(id);
                    }
                } finally {
                    this._stopDispatching();
                }
            };
```

**UPDATE:** It appears as though making an asynchronous call in **webAppsAPI.accounts.get()** clears the **AppDispatcher._callbacks**?!?! Why would this be happening and how do we get around it?